# How to find all twins from family trees in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to find all twins from a few families that I have as data.

The format is family(Father,Mother,[Children]). and each person is formatted as person(Name,Surname,date(DD/MM/YYYY)).

```
family(person(mike, norton, date(13, octomber, 1973), works(chef, 7000)),
person(jane, norton, date(12, may, 1977), unemployed),
[person(nick, norton, date(22, august, 1997), unemployed),
person(bill, norton, date(18, january, 2001), unemployed)]).

family(person(george, smith, date(1, january, 1965), works(hotel, 5600)),
person(helen, smith, date(23, november, 1971), works(hnm, 3100)),
[person(jessica, smith, date(22, may, 1993), unemployed),
person(jack, smith, date(16, march, 1996), works(police, 4000)),
person(anthony, smith, date(9, may, 1998), works(guitarist, 3400))]).

child(X):- family(_, _, Children), member(X, Children).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
child(X):-
  family(_, _, Children),
  member(X, Children).

twins(Child1,Child2) :- child(Child1),child(Child2),
    Child1=person(Name1,Surname1,Date1,_),
    Child2=person(Name2,Surname2,Date2,_),
    Name1@>Name2, %We use the operator to print the twins only once.
    Surname1=Surname2,
    Date1=Date2.
```